# Foreign key invalid with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

So i am trying to create a table with a foreign key, but it always says that it cannot find the foreign key. heres the code:

```
 public class Tecnologies
    {
        [Key]
        public int TecId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
```

this one works, then i try to create this one:

```
 public class UserTecnologies
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserTecId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public UserProfile User { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TecId")]
        public virtual Tecnologies Tecnology { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Rating { get; set; }
    }
```

and it gives me the error :

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Tecnology' on type 'ESW_CloddOffice.Models.UserTecnologies' is not valid. The foreign key name 'TecId' was not found on the dependent type 'ESW_CloddOffice.Models.UserTecnologies'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

The names are correct, what am i missing ?

Comment: Something to note is that Tecnologies appears to be spelled wrong. Did you mean Technologies?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found what i was doing wrong. Heres the correct code:

```
  public class UserTecnologies
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserTecId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
        public virtual int UserProfileId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Tecnology")]
        public virtual int TecnologyId { get; set; }

        public virtual Tecnologies Tecnology { get; set; }
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Rating { get; set; }
    }
```

Was creating the foreign key the wrong way .

Answer (score 0):

The `ForeignKey` attribute requires that an actual property on the entity match the name you pass in. It doesn't just tell EF what to call the key at the database level.

You either need to actually add a `TecId` property:

```
public int TecId { get; set; }
```

Or use fluent configuration, instead:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserTechnologies>() 
.HasRequired(c => c.Technology)
.WithMany() 
.Map(m => m.MapKey("TecId"));
```